# Elements appear on one line instead of separate lines

Tags: html, css

I want to create an accordion with nested levels. So I have used Angular's accordion directive to create nested levels. But the last level contains a list which should get displayed one by one on new line. But what happens in my case all sub categories gets listed in one line.

I saw in the console that all sub categories are getting listed in one panel body. They should get separate class for each of the sub categories. Any one know how to do that? This is code of my accordion:

```
<div style='padding-top:50px;'>
   <accordion>
      <accordion-group heading="Title">
         <accordion  close-others="oneAtATime">
            <accordion-group heading="Category">
                <span>Subcat1</span>
                <span>Subcat2</span>
            </accordion-group>
         </accordion>
      </accordion-group>
   </accordion>
</div>
```

Directive **accordion-group** is replacing following code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">    
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a href class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" accordion-transclude="heading">
                <span ng-class="{\'text-muted\': isDisabled}">{{heading}}</span>
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse" collapse="!isOpen">
        <div class="panel-body" ng-transclude>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So whatever I am printing inside **`<accordion-group></accordion-group>`** is getting placed in div having class **panel-body**. But as I am printing Subcat1 and Subcat2 inside **accordion-group** is going in one div **panel-body**. Like this:

```
<div ng-transclude="" class="panel-body">
   <span class="ng-scope">Subcat1</span>
   <span class="ng-scope">Subcat2</span>
</div>
```

But I want separate **panel-body** div for each of Subcat. Like

```
<div class="panel-body"><span>Subcat1</span></div>
<div class="panel-body"><span>Subcat1</span></div>
```

For more details see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yWQxQN4Vh0XmLSQ8hV2P?p=preview)

Sorry for my english..:P

Comment: You could add the class names to the spans from the HTML? Also, to get these displaying on new lines, it would be semantic to use a HTML list.

Comment: I tried to add class in span but its not giving me desired result.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Span is an inline element. If you change this to be a list items for example, they will not be in a line as you describe. Apart from this, the question doesn't ask anything else.

Comment: I am editing my question. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<span>` is defined as an inline element and will on its own not introduce any line breaks.

To achieve the output on multiple lines, you would either want to use elements that do that on their own, or make use of custom styles, usually via CSS.

If you really have a list of subcategories, you could for example use an ordered list `<ol>`.

Simple example:

```
<accordion>
  <accordion-group heading="Title">
     <accordion  close-others="oneAtATime">
        <accordion-group heading="Category">
            <ol>
               <li>Subcat1</li>
               <li>Subcat2</li>
            </ol>
        </accordion-group>
     </accordion>
  </accordion-group>
```

Updated Plunker: [Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vv0DWehGhyi6eYkQCqvN?p=preview)

But this has nothing to do with your tags `angularjs` or the angular-ui `accordion`, it's an issue of plain HTML.

Comment: Actually I want to repeat **<div ng-transclude="" class="panel-body"></div>** for each of the Subcat. But this div is in **accordion-group** directive's template. So how i can customize it? In my question as well I had mentioned this.